# Rails routes not loaded in features test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am using rspec-rails 3.5.2, capybara 2.5.0, rails 4.2.4

This is my test:

```
#spec/features/visitors/sign_up_spec.rb
feature 'Sign Up' do

  scenario 'visitor can sign up with valid email address and password' do
    visit new_user_registration_path
    fill_in 'user_email', with: "#{SecureRandom.hex}}@example.com"
    fill_in 'user_password', with: "password"
    click_button 'Sign up'

    #other code here
  end
end
```

The `new_user_registration_path` method not exist and this is the error:

```
$ rspec spec/features/visitors/sign_up_spec.rb                                                                                                                       
F
Failures:

  1) Sign Up visitor can sign up with valid email address and password
     Failure/Error: visit new_user_registration_path

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/features/visitors/sign_up_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.17765 seconds (files took 3.54 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/visitors/sign_up_spec.rb:14 # Sign Up visitor can sign up with valid email address and password
```

If I try `visit '/'` it works.

This is my `.rspec` file

```
$ cat .rspec                                                                                                                                                         
--color
--require rails_helper
```

Rails routes are not loaded.

I have used Pry to investigate:

```
    14:   scenario 'visitor can sign up with valid email address and password' do
    15:     binding.pry
 => 16:     visit new_user_registration_path
    17:     fill_in 'user_email', with: "#{SecureRandom.hex}}@example.com"

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SignUp>)> new_user_registration_path
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@project/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:769:in `optimize_routes_generation?'
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SignUp>)>
```

routes:

```
$ rake routes | grep "new_user_registration"                                                                                                                         
     new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                   my_devise/registrations#new
```

This is from console:

```
$ rails c test                                                                                                                                                       
Running via Spring preloader in process 5692
Loading test environment (Rails 4.2.4)
2.2.6 :001 > Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_user_registration_path
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

Ideas?

Comment: Assuming you have correctly installed rspec-rails it should be automatic from - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example/feature_example_group.rb#L15 .  I would say that this is working correctly for you since it's not telling you the xxx_path method doesn't exist, it's telling you there is an error in the method.  Check your routes.rb file for any recent changes, and make sure you didn't screw it up somehow.

Comment: and if you look at the location of the errror - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L769 - you can see that its because you don't have your default_url_options set for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try including in you `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
```